# State Change After Update (by Another User) But Before Poll

Tags: ajax, web-applications, polling

suppose we have the following scenario:

1. 2 users both signal ready to play, the rails app receives it and starts a game
2. one of the 2 users issue a "forfeit" via ajax immediately (im assuming it's not possible to prevent that, amirite?)
3. by the time the other user polls to figure out whether a game has started, the game has already ended and scores updated
4. that user is confused

I'm not quite sure what to do here. Can anyone give me some ideas?

---

Alright, I figured out what I did wrong. (cant self answer yet because my rep is too low)

When a user polls to figure out whether his/her game has started, and to receive moves and etc, I check "game in progress" and "user = user polling" attributes to figure out what to respond. But that's wrong, because as soon as the ends, this logic fails to find the relevant game to retrieve data from and give back to the user.

What I'm think of right now is, add "end game has been polled" as an attribute to the game object (well, playing objects through relationships) so if a game ended but has not been polled, the user will receive it once then respond to confirm. Then the game will not be polled again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag indicating the game has ended should allow for different values indicating why the game ended. When player 1 forfeits, the flag is updated to indicate forfeiture. Then when player 2 polls to get status, he is told of the forfeiture.

Comment: But how would my model know to even look at it. I mean if I just pull out the most recent game every poll then the user would be receiving historic data every poll.

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not understanding your question and context.

Comment: So add "end game has been polled" to the set of states?

Comment: Do you have a game state table or object that is maintained at the server? If so, when player1 forfeits, the game state is "ended" with perhaps a causeCode of "forfeit" or something along those lines. I don't know what your data structure looks like, but the concepts should apply to it.

Comment: Well, I actually just figured out how to do it and where my model need to be redesigned. I already have what you said but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out what I did wrong.

When a user polls to figure out whether his/her game has started, and to receive moves and etc, I check "game in progress" and "user = user polling" attributes to figure out what to respond. But that's wrong, because as soon as the ends, this logic fails to find the relevant game to retrieve data from and give back to the user.

What I'm think of right now is, add "end game has been polled" as an attribute to the game object (well, playing objects through relationships) so if a game ended but has not been polled, the user will receive it once then respond to confirm. Then the game will not be polled again.

However, there is now a new question, as in what if there are multiple state changes in-between polls.

Maybe polling for state is just wrong? Perhaps I need a buffer queue that records state changes in order for polling? I don't know yet.